# Can we reopen the question about restarting the Tor browser?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, scope

This is a question about how to restart the Tor browser:

- [Restart Tor Browser after closing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217092/restart-tor-browser-after-closing)

The OP's motivation for wanting to do so is a bug. This question, however, is not a bug report. The bug is *not* that the browser won't restart. Answers to this question would help anyone who wants to restart the Tor browser.

Therefore, I recommend we reopen this question.

If anyone thinks this should stay closed, I recommend posting an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reopened. (My old reopen vote had expired, but it got reopen votes from one off the original close voters and a moderator.)

Anyone should feel free to post an answer here (particularly if you disagree and think it should still be closed), but it seems this situation is resolved.